# Managed metadata column filtering in M365/Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata

I am building out managed metadata columns and would love to be able to display or auto assign the top term when selecting a sub term since it doesn't appear you can include descendants like you used to be able to.

Example

Term Set: Automobile

Term:

Car

> Color

> Blue

I would create a column for Car and when a user chooses Blue I would like to somehow show Blue is a child of Color and then be able to sort/filter by Color.

So far the only way i see it's possible is to display entire path to term and make MM column multi-select. Not super useful as filtering, sorting and grouping with multi select gets confusing for end users and honestly it looks like crap.

Would be nice if Blue was selected it was identified as being a Color.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no OOB way to achieve this in SharePoint online modern experience, as a workaround, we suggest you **Return to classic SharePoint**:

[image]

Comment: so it's possible in SP, but using teams interface doesn't look like it's doable.

Comment: Yes this will not work in Teams since there is no classic experience in Teams.